# How to see if there is a pattern between numbers in a database using python

Tags: python, database, numbers, sequence

I was working on a database using python and I was wondering if there was a way to determine if there was a pattern between the numbers in my database?  I would like it to check if there is a pattern and determine what the most logical next numbers would be.  I do not currently have any code but if someone can help please do.

Comment: You may want to look into using Python for Data Science.  Though I'm not too familiar with the topic myself, I know that you will have to learn about the modules in Python that are made for this purpose.

Comment: For any finite sequence of numbers, there are an infinite number of polynomial functions that satisfy `f(i) = sequence[i]`. You can then generate however many additional numbers you want. So yes, you can absolutely find a pattern. But almost all of those functions have no predictive power. For example, finding a polynomial that matches the winning lottery numbers for the last fifty years won't tell you what tomorrow's numbers are. If you want something more specific than just "a pattern", you're going to have to give us more information about your numbers.